# Terraform ignore empty list value in resources

Tags: python, list, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have module to create Azure VM. since azure australia central region does't support zones, so i want to pass empty list. just tried with if condtion its not working as expected.

terrafor version: v0.11.13 (note - I can't update terrafrom version. its has lot of dependencies)

This working, if av_zone length is not zero:

```
zones=["${length(var.av_zone)} != 0 ? ${element(var.av_zone, count.index%length(var.av_zone))}"]
```

if az_zone length is zero getting below error:

> - module.create-vm-taskflow.azurerm_virtual_machine.virtualmachine[1]: __builtin_IntMath: divide by zero in:

expected output:

if az_zone lenght is zero, then vaule should be empty list []

if az_zone lenght is not zero, then value should be [${element(var.av_zone, count.index%length(var.av_zone))}]

Comment: Something like: `zones = length(var.az_zone) == 0 ? [] :  [${element(var.az_zone, count.index%length(var.az_zone))}]`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot it was an older version of Terraform: zones = "${length(var.az_zone)} == 0 ? [] :  [${element(var.az_zone, count.index%length(var.az_zone))}"]

Comment: @MarkoE I have tried but no luck.                                                                            zones = "${length(var.av_zone)} == 0 ? [] : [${element(var.av_zone, count.index%length(var.av_zone))}]"                                                                        
 Error:  

Error: module.create-vm-taskflow.azurerm_virtual_machine.virtualmachine: 2 error(s) occurred:

* module.create-vm-taskflow.azurerm_virtual_machine.virtualmachine[0]: __builtin_IntMath: divide by zero in:

Answer (score 0):

**would suggest you to please use in this format once :**

```
zones = "${length(var.az_zone) > 0 ? [${element(var.az_zone, count.index%length(var.az_zone))}] : 0}"
```

For more information please refer this [***github***](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/12570) discussion